# How to force Apollo Client to respect 'network-only' fetchPolicy when ssrMode is set to true?

Tags: reactjs, caching, vite, server-side-rendering, apollo

I'm using Apollo client to fetch data during SSR.

When I pass `{ssrMode: true}` in the client option, Apollo Client only fetches the initial request during server side rendering and serves any future request directly from the cache until I restart the server.

This issue behaves differently if `{ssrMode}` is omitted during Serverside Rendering. Then Apollo executes the query again, but when using `useSuspenseQuery` it does **not** suspend until the serverside cache is ready, serving a a stale cache which causes a hydration error.

I need the *serverside* request made with `useSuspenseQuery` to **always** fetch from network or at least respect the fetchPolicy passed to `useSuspenseQuery`

Suppose a client mutates data after the page has loaded. How can I make sure the serverside request does an actual request and does not serve cached data?

Do I manually need to clear the cache on the server before a request is made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apollo Client is not meant to have one long-running cache instance during SSR.

You should create a new ApolloClient and InMemoryCache instance for every new incoming request.
Otherwise you run the risk of leaking sensitive user data between different requests.

That also means that this question will not be relevant anymore - if you always start with a new empty cache, it will always make network requests.

All that said, `ssrMode` is meant for `renderToString` SSR, and `useSuspenseQuery` probably doesn't work well with it.
As mentioned in your other question, I'd really want to encourage you to wait for the official streaming support to be released in a week or two (or build the package yourself from source right now), streaming SSR is extremely complicated to support with a data fetching library, so I wouldn't recommend to roll your own solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to answer my second question as well. I wasn't aware that you should instantiate a new client on every request. That makes a whole lot of sense and will solve my problem! Sure, I'll definitely update my implementation once official code has been released. However, everything is already working fine with `useSuspenseQuery`, Vite and `renderToPipeable` stream. It doesn't need much custom code to get it running actually. If i'm not using `getDataFromTree` wrong, that's pretty much the only workaround needed.

Comment: That's pretty much the problem `getDataFromTree` doesn't really work in that case, since that's made for a "render everything, then move data over, then render everything in the browser" situation. But you are in streaming SSR. If you have five suspense boundaries, you want to transport data at least at 5 different points of time - the server still fetches data while the browser in parts is already interactive.

Comment: Streaming SSR is a completely new mechanism (and ironically, React is still missing the building blocks for data fetching libraries to support it, so we have to work around that).
If you want to do some reading, I'd recommend this: https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client-nextjs/pull/9
Also see the review comments where I discuss the details with Dan Abramov, they give good context. (In the end, it's really more on streaming than RSC)

Comment: It's pretty neat, a few years ago you couldn't even use Suspense on the server side. Now if done right, it can be used to decrease FCP, LCP and TTI. I just wonder how Apollo would handle partial rehydration if some elements are interactive before the cache has been streamed to the client. Ideally you wouldn't need to rely on serializing the cache, exposing it through a script tag after everything loaded, but **stream** the cache to the client as it's being populated on the server. This would allow the client to receive parts of the cache during client side hydration.

Comment: That's what the package does.